# Broken mimetype defaults? default apps dont work

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, mate-desktop

On arch linux default programs do not matter.

When I open a file I downloaded from my browser, whether its a pic, archive or otherwise, It always just opens the file in another browser, which downloads it again.

Text files are problematic too, they never open in the right text editor, it seems to change daily which one it defaults to.

I also cannot set my default browser, setting it does nothing and my default browser seems to have a mind of its own.

Today, it is firefox, other times it is seamonkey or mosaic.

I am not really sure what to do about this I have hit "set default" and set "open with this progam every time" in mate or kde a thousand times and it does not do anything.

Comment: Start by checking `xdg-mime query default <mime-type>` to see what application is the default for `<mime-type>`.

Comment: xdg-mime query default application/xml
nedit-usercreated-0.desktop

xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http
chromium.desktop
xdg-mime query default application/zip
engrampa.desktop


why does it not obey these?

Comment: I just opened a zip file from my browser. Earlier, doing this would just open it in another browser. 
But just now it opened in nautilus. 
Then I tried to open a seperate zip file, which opened in a 7zip GUI.